# How to convert from plain text to URL Encoded html

Tags: html, text, hex

I need to know how to convert a text message to URL Encoded html. (I mean the HTML code that's actually being sent to the web server)

Example of the conversation:

**Text:** `Hello, Brother!`
**HTML:** `Hello%2C+Brother%21`

Would be very thankful if anyone helped me.

Comment: That's not HTML.  HTML code is not sent to the web server.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It sounds like the term you're looking for is "URL Encoded" rather than "parsed HTML"

Answer (score 1):

You can URL encode client-side with JavaScript's [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/17447.asp) method. If you are using a JavaScript library such as jQuery, they will handle it for you when you encapsulate your data in an object, e.g., [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) using the `data` parameter.